Backend в telegram web app
вот сделал фронтенд для telegram web app далее нужно сделать бэкенд, подключить базу данных и т.д, но как это реализовать не имею даже представления. Подскажите как вообще это работает, как стоит правильно это сделать.
Единственное что я видел это что-то про разделение на микросервисы. И вообще бэкенд это получается он отвечает только за функции веб-приложения да? Например ввод пользователем

В контексте веба бэкенд — это то, что принимает HTTP-запросы и отсылает какие-нибудь ответы на них. Что и за что он отвечает — вы как разработчик бэкенда сами решаете. Думаю, создание бэкенда для telegram web app не отличается от создания какого угодно другого бэкенда

То есть делать весь бэкенд для фронтенд не надо а лишь сделать его для некоторых функций например ввод данных пользователем и тд? И еще можно ли отслеживать количество нажатий на кнопки типо что выбора пользователь и сколько раз за все время для аналитики

Бэкенд просто принимает HTTP-запросы и отвечает на них. Если вы хотите что-то сделать на бэкенде — вы должны придумать, как на стороне фронтенда запихнуть это что-то в HTTP-запрос, а потом на стороне бэкенда прочитать из HTTP-запроса то, что туда было запихнуто, и сделать с этим что хотите (например, записать в ту же базу)

А почитать об этом можно где то ? А лучше посмотреть
